# how to restore `timestamp` value in Sybase ASE 15.5?

Tags: java, timestamp, sap-ase, apache-metamodel

I am `reading` `data` from one Table of `Sybase ASE 15.5` `database` and `inserting` that `data` back into another target `Sybase ASE 15.5` `database`. All `source` and `destination` data matched instead of `timestamp` column.

As what I know about the `timestamp` column is that it updates automatically:

> Every time a row containing a timestamp column is inserted or updated,
>   the timestamp column is automatically updated. A table can have only
>   one column of the timestamp datatype. A column named timestamp will
>   automatically have the system datatype timestamp.

Source: https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Sybase-ASE-3/page/4/Data-Types

Therefore, when I am restoring that `timestamp` data back into target database it does not match with the actual one.

Here is the screen short to Source Table

[image]

Here is the screen short to Destination Table

[image]

How to restore the exact value of timestamp column?

FYI:

I am using `Apache Meta-model` to query data from source table and restore that data back into the target database.
`As you can see timestamp is an array of bytes so I am extracting data as an array of bytes and restore it again as array of bytes but the value timestamp column is being changed when restore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. A timestamp column will always be updated; this value these columns contain is the 'database timestamp', which is at the basis of the transaction mechanism in ASE, and is incremented for *every* inserted or updated row or any other change in the database.
The name 'timestamp' is misleading however, since it has absolutely nothing to do with real-world time. It's just a 6-byte counter that will only increase over the lifetime of the database.

If you wanted a real-world time in those columns, use datatype 'datetime' or 'bigdatetime' instead.

Comment: Bulk copy can insert any valid value in a timestamp column. The bulk copy API is not available in all programing environments; in fact, in very few, maybe only with native CT-lib Open Client in C. The alternative is to use the bcp utility. This could be workable only when done very few times in batch processes, because using bcp requires creating a file per bcp execution. bcp doesn't look suitable for an online application.